# how to filter List<String> in an ArrayList<List<String> in java

Tags: java, arraylist

how can i do to filter out which List as below contain the String "1" in the index 0 of the List inside the ArrayList

```
List<List<String>> a = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
a.add(Arrays.asList("1","2","3"));
a.add(Arrays.asList("4","5","6"));
a.add(Arrays.asList("2","1","8"));
a.add(Arrays.asList("1","1","8"));
```

and expected result after do filter is : List index 0,3 in the ArrayList

Comment: Just to clarify - should the result be the lists themselves or just their indexes?

Comment: the result expect is that: ("1","2","3"), ("1","1","8")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to retrieve the indexes:

```
int[] indexArray = IntStream.range(0, a.size()).filter(x -> a.get(x).get(0).equals("1")).toArray();
```

to retrieve the actual lists:

```
List<List<String>> resultSet = a.stream().filter(x -> x.get(0).equals("1")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```